# Botman PHP 7.2.4 opcache

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

I am tring to get a simple conversation working and the response fails, I need to know how to use opcache with botman and php 7.2.4 - WAMP

I have modified the php.ini file adding the zend_extension setting, following the documentation I have use:

```
use BotMan\BotMan\Cache\DoctrineCache;

$botman = BotManFactory::create($config, new DoctrineCache($doctrineCacheDriver));
```

This gives and undefined variable: doctrineCacheDriver error

The function uses a $driver variable, is there additional settings that need to be configured.

Any help setting up cache, php 7 on wamp, would be much appreciated.

Comment: 7.4 eh?  Think you're a little ahead of yourself.

Comment: @Devon 7.2.4 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer to this or someone in the future follow the following steps.

1. Install APCu on Windows (WAMPP/XAMPP) using  [this guide](http://robert-rusu.blogspot.com/2014/06/install-apcu-on-windows.html).
2. Run composer require doctrine/cache from your CLI inside your project/ app directory

Then make an instance of the cache class/driver

```
$doctrineCacheDriver = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcuCache();
```

Thats when you can pass it to BotmanFactory as the as a parameter like below

```
$botman = BotManFactory::create($config, new DoctrineCache($doctrineCacheDriver));
```

You were getting that error because the

> $doctrineCacheDriver

was not defined